# Best way to retrieve a text inputs of dynamically generated text box

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Need help, what is the best way to retrieve text input from a dynamically generated textbox in asp.net so I can later use them to update a database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is pretty basic and there are tons of examples online.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

// For Generating textbox

```
TextBox text = new TextBox();
```

//For Getting its Text

```
string MyValue = text.Text;
```

hence. You can Get the Value of your dynamically generated textbox by its object !

Comment: thats not fair  i provide an valid answer  still get the down vote

Comment: sorry, not on purpose... will try to undo it...

Comment: yeah off-course buddy you can delete your question if you think i was on wrong way but down Voting is not gud thanks !

Comment: Sorry Syed, I'm new here and I'm not familiar of how things work yet. And to be honest, I didn't know that we can vote up and down, that vote down didn't come from me.